# React Native Button is still visible but not touchable after setState change

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a render method that checks an array length in my State and displays a button if the length > 0.  Clicking on the button will alter the state array value back to [].

Clicking the button does reset the array value, the state gets change, and the view is re-rendered.  But the button remains visible on the view, but is not touchable, sits behind other elements, and I cannot even inspect in the debug. Its basically just an artifact.

Pretty sure I'm missing a simple react state / render concept. Any thoughts? Thanks.

Here is the render code:

```
render() {
 return (
  <Container theme={theme} style={{ backgroundColor: '#000000' }}>
    <View style={styles.mapView}>
      <MapView style={styles.map}
        mapType='satellite'
        showsUserLocation={true}
        showsCompass={true}
        followsUserLocation={false}
        onLongPress={(e) => this.onMapLongPress(e)}
        initialRegion={{
            latitude: 34.186129,
            longitude: -84.546111,
            latitudeDelta: 0.0012,
            longitudeDelta: 0.0012,
        }}>
        {this.state.mapMarkers.map(marker => (
        <MapView.Marker
          key={marker.key}
          coordinate={marker.coordinate}
          draggable
          centerOffset={{ x: 0, y: -50 }}
          onDragEnd={(e) => this.onMarkerEndDrag(e, marker.key)}
        >
            <TargetMarker distance={this.calculateTargetDistance(marker.coordinate.latitude, marker.coordinate.longitude)} metric={this.state.distanceUnitMetric.toUpperCase()} />
        </MapView.Marker>
      ))}
        { this.state.mapMarkers.length > 0 ? (
            <Button style={styles.deleteTargetButton} onPress={() => this.setState({mapMarkers: [] })}>
              <Icon name="delete-forever" size={30} color={GOLD_COLOR}/>
            </Button>
          ) : null
        }
      </MapView>
    </View>
  </Container>
 );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Render usually needs to return either a component or null, so maybe try explicitly setting that component to null when it shouldn't render? So something like:

```
{ this.state.mapMarkers.length > 0 ? (
    <Button style={styles.deleteTargetButton} onPress={() => this.setState({mapMarkers: [] })}>
        <Icon name="delete-forever" size={30} color={GOLD_COLOR}/>
    </Button>
) : null }
```

Comment: Thanks for the thought, but no luck. Although I'm guessing this change can't hurt and might provide better stability going forward so I'll remember this one.

Comment: Strange. Can you post the entire render method?

Comment: Sure can.  Just updated the post with the full render(). Thanks again.

Comment: Try moving it out of the Mapview component

Comment: @MattAft Ha, that did the trick.  Not sure why I thought I needed it inside the component just to make sure it sat on top. I was styling it all as if it was independent of the MapView anyway. Thanks for your help.